# Como fazer validação de celular e de data em uma aplicação em C++

Tags: c, validação

Olá, sou iniciante e estou com uma atividade para fazer, necessito dos seguintes passos:

. No atributo celular, é preciso validar a entrada para que sejam aceitos números dentro do intervalo 900000000 a 999999999 apenas, e caso o número esteja fora deste intervalo, pedir nova digitação.
. Validar também a digitação do dia do mês em um intervalo de 1 a 31 apenas, assim como mês entre 1 e 12, e por fim, ano entre 1900 e 2021, reduzindo as chances de entradas de dados inadequados para cada variável, e em caso de falha em qualquer um dos três dados, solicitar nova digitação

eu já fiz uma parte mas essas validações eu não estou conseguindo fazer, a atividade é para sexta e estou sem tempo. segue em baixo o meu código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

typedef struct {
    char nome[3];

    int celular;

    int diaN;

    int mesN;

    int anoN;

} 
dados;


int main (){


    int i, j;

    long long dig1, dig2, aux;

    dados y[3];

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    for (i=0; i<3; i++){

        printf ("\n*** Cadastro %d ***\n", i+1);
        
        printf ("Nome: ");
        scanf (" %s", y[i].nome);
        
        
        
        
        printf ("Celular: ");
        scanf ("%d", &y[i].celular);
        
        
        
        
        printf ("Data de Nascimento (dia): ");
        scanf ("%d", &y[i].diaN);
        
        
        
        printf ("Data de Nascimento (mês): ");
        scanf ("%d", &y[i].mesN);
    
        
        
        
        printf ("Data de Nascimento (ano): ");
        scanf ("%d", &y[i].anoN);
   
    printf ("\n\n*** CONSULTA NO CADASTRO ***\n");
    printf ("Escolha uma posição a exibir (1 a 3): ");
    scanf ("%d", &i);
    printf ("Nome: %s\n", y[i-1].nome);
    printf ("Celular: %d\n", y[i-1].celular);
    printf ("Data de Nascimento: %d/%d/%d\n", y[i-1].diaN);
}
}
```

Comment: "eu já fiz uma parte mas essas validações eu não estou conseguindo fazer" - em que parte do código estão essas validações ?

Comment: eu tentei fazer a validação dentro do for, abrir uma condição if mas não entra na condição, não está nesse código que eu postei, meu erro

Comment: tecnicamente ficaria assim if (diaN=0 & diaN<=3){    printf(") }

Comment: não use int para esses valores. não vai operar com eles. Só vai ficar mais difícil assim